# MongoDb replication lag increasing and drop collection command

Tags: mongodb, replication, database-replication, replicaset

We are experiencing a strange behaviour in a production environment related to mongodb replica set and replication lag.

Basically we have an installation with a mongodb replica set and an application which writes to the primary node of the replica set. Sometimes the app could become write-intensive (this is not entirely predictable and is related to the user loads which can vary from time to time). We have a six nodes replica set distributed over two data centers.

Everything has worked quite well up to a new release of the app which has changed the pattern in which data are written to the database. **The main difference between the two versions of the app is that the latter make an intensive use of the drop collection command (data are written to a temp collection, then the temp collection is renamed and if a collection with the same name exists then such a collection is dropped. This is accomplished with [this mongodb instruction](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) by setting the option dropTarget to true)**.

The symptom we are now experiencing is that some of the secondary nodes present random peaks in the replication lag. Looking at the logs, the peaks seem to be related to the drop collection commands, but we are not able to reproduce the 
same behaviour in our test environment and we cannot conclude for sure that the application changes are the root cause of the increasing replication lags.

Looking at the mongodb official documentation it seems that there is not a clear and well documented correlation between drop collection commands and replication lag increasing.

Does anyone has already experienced the same issue ?